# How to create new object for class without using its module name?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class as like below and I have this in a separate file called File1

```
module test {
    export class myClass{
        constructor(MyName: any) {
        }

    }
}
```

In another one file called File2 am creating object for above class like below.

```
module test {
    class myClass2{
        var object = new myClass("name");
    }
}
```

if the above object creation typescript code is converted into javascript code it looks like this

```
var object = new test.myClass("name");
```

But actually i need it to be look like this in js

```
var object = new myClass("name");
```

Can anyone please help me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
module test {
    export class myClass{
        constructor(MyName: any) {
        }
    }
}

module test {
    var myClass = test.myClass;
    var object = new myClass("name");    
}
```

The generated js:

```
var myClass = test.myClass;
var object = new myClass("name");
```

[Try It](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=module%20test%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20myClass%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor%28MyName%3a%20any%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%0Amodule%20test%20%7B%0A%09var%20myClass%20=%20test.myClass;%0A%20%20%20%20var%20object%20=%20new%20myClass%28%22name%22%29;%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0A)

**Update**: If you don't want to see any `test.` in your js don't put the class in the module i.e:

```
class myClass{
    constructor(MyName: any) {
    }
}


module test {   
    var object = new myClass("name");    
}
```

**Update 2:** Since you want to use existing Js from typescript you need to use an ambient declaration i.e. `declare` :

```
declare class myClass{
    constructor(MyName: any);
}


module test {   
    var object = new myClass("name");    
}
```

Comment: I dont want to see any test.myClass in my .js

Comment: Why not? Why do you care what the compiled JS looks like so much? This is a big code smell and could use some explanation

Comment: I already have "myClass()" function in some other "exsisting.js" file , so i want my compiled .js to use "myClass()" function from "exsisting.js". Converting that exsisting.js to .ts is too complicated so is there any why to do that without converting entire file to .ts.